# Is readsome() appropriate to read binary data on Windows?

Tags: c++, iostream

**Context:** I am trying to read the content of a PNG picture in C++ to send it later to my Android app. To do so, I open the file in binary mode, read it's content by chuncks of 512 bytes, then send the data to the app. I'm on Windows.

**Issue:** I use an *ifstream* instance and the *readsome()* function as shown below, and it returns me 512, which is what I expected since I asked to read 512 bytes. However, it seems that I am far from really having 512 bytes in my buffer, which confuses me. While I debug my programm step by step, the number of char in the buffer seems random, but is never 512 as expected.

**Code:**

```
int currentByteRead = 0;
std::ifstream fl(imgPath.toStdString().c_str(), ios_base::binary);
fl.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
int length = fl.tellg();

char *imgBytes = new char[512];

fl.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
// Send the img content by blocks of 512 bytes
while(currentByteRead + 512 < length) {
    int nbRead = fl.readsome(imgBytes, 512); // nbRead is always set to 512 here

    if(fl.fail()) {
        qDebug() << "Error when reading file content";
    }

    sendMessage(...);
    currentByteRead += 512;
    imgBytes = new char[512];
}

// Send the remaining data
int nbRemainingBytes = length - currentByteRead;
fl.readsome(imgBytes, nbRemainingBytes);
sendMessage(...);
fl.close();
currentByteRead += nbRemainingBytes;
```

The length I get at the beginning is the correct one, and it seems there is no error. But it is as if not all the data was copied into the buffer during the *readsome()* call.

**Questions:** Did I misunderstood something about the *readsome()* function ? Is there something related to Windows causing this behaviour ? Is there a more appropriate way to proceed ?

Comment: Surely you don’t mean to allocate `new char[512]` *every time*.

Comment: Why do you think that your buffer is “far from really having 512 bytes”?

Comment: You are right, I changed the implementation to have a cleaner code with a char vector. To answer your second question, it seems that the buffer only contains characters until the first '\n' found. And the _readsome()_ still returns 512 everytime. I will edit my post with the code I have now since it works.

Comment: Meanwhile, what is `nbRead` in the original code?  You never use it.

Comment: I posted an answer as you suggested. `nbRead` was just used to store the return value of the `readsome` function. It was helpful for debugging purposes only in this first implementation. I edited the code for clarity.

Comment: The point is that `nbRead` is never guaranteed to be the number of bytes you asked for–you have to use it to find out how much data was read!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do what I wanted, and as suggested by David Herring I will put here my answer.

**My thoughts about the issue:** If I use a *std::ifstream::pos_type* variable instead of an *int*, the correct number of bytes is read and put in the buffer. This was not the case when using an int, as if the chars were only written in the buffer until a given (random ?) point. I am not sure to understand why this behavior occurred. My guess was that I had issues with '\n' characters, but the randomness of the final content of the buffer is still unclear for me.

**Correction:** This is the working code I finally reached nonetheless. Starting with this, I was able to do what I had in mind.

```
std::ifstream ifs(imgPath.toStdString().c_str(), std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
std::ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();
int length = ifs.tellg();
std::vector<char>  result(pos);
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
ifs.read(result.data(), pos);
ifs.close();
```

I hope this will help others. Thank you David for your suggestions.